# ReferenceError: transitioning is not defined in rails3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, assets

I am working with rails3.
It had different javascript libraries like moment( for datetime picker), and init(for ckeditor).

When i use DateTime Picker it comes pretty good after clicking on time if i go back to calender again it is raising

> ReferenceError: transitioning is not defined in rails3

in browser.

Not able to resolve

Check my Gemfile

```
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
gem "jquery-datatables-rails", "~> 1.12.2"
gem 'jquery-ui-rails','4.2.0'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails",'2.2.8'
gem 'fancybox-rails'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '~> 2.5.0'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

and my application.js is

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require jquery_ujs 
//= require twitter/bootstrap 
//= require ckeditor/init 
//= require fancybox 
//= require moment 
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

And loading file in

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/twitter/bootstrap.js?body=1">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/ckeditor/init.js?body=1">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js?body=1">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.browser.js?body=1">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jquery.fancybox.js?body=1">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/fancybox.js?body=1">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/moment.js?body=1">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js?body=1">
```

The error raises in browser sometimes pointing "init.js" and "datetimepicker.js"

Please save my time.

Comment: `init.js` is dependent on some other libraries i guess, so you need to call them in proper order.

Comment: can u please tell me proper order. Because i tried most of the ways but failed

Comment: And it it working in local production and development mode

Comment: could you check if your getting any error on your`s console

Comment: i didn't find any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve ur problem by using bootstrap datepicker file for  bootstrao 3.0 version .

**Reference :**
Plesae Refer below link for Updated File ,

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

```
rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
     href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.3.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js" ></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" ></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js" ></script>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.0.0/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js" ></script>

          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.4.0/lang/en-gb.js" ></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

**fiddle ::**

http://jsfiddle.net/Ev6Md/